# Starting a process using windows service

Tags: c#, service, process

i have written a windows service using c# in VS2012. This windows service simply monitor a process in task manager wheather the process is running or not. if not running, then the service will fetch the process exe file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\myInstalledApp\myapp.exe". the code below works fine when i test the code from VS2012. But after deploying it, its not invoking the process properly.

```
         while (true)
            {
                logClient = Process.GetProcessesByName("myApp");
                taskManager = Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr");

                if (logClient.Length == 0 && taskManager.Length == 1)
                {
                    replaceList.Add("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = GetPath();
                    myProcess.Start();
                    SendMail(to,cc,subject, body);
                }
                else if (logClient.Length == 0 && taskManager.Length == 0)
                {
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = GetPath();
                    myProcess.Start();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

when i manually end the myApp.exe process from taskmgr, it restart the application and the application is working fine when the code is running from vs2012. after deploying and installing the service to the system, i close the application from taskmgr but it is not revoked by the windows service like before. 
In taskmgr, username for the myapp.exe is myName when it is normaly running, username changes to System when i end the process myapp.exe. but myapplication.exe is not working after this.

Comment: The application may well be starting, but it's in the context of a system service and can have no UI. A service has no (and should have no) direct access to the desktop; what would it do when no one is logged in, or when multiple desktops are active via RDP?

Comment: what should i do now? should i start the service manually if the process ended?